# How to expanding column height in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is a definite structure:

```
<div class="container-fluid main">
  <div class="col-lg-4 left_top">Left</div>

  <div class="col-lg-8 right_top">
    <div class="col-lg-6 second">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 third">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8 bottom_center">Our tabs</div>

</div>
```

It is necessary to lower the column (green) at a resolution *md reduced in width to the level of the blue column.
At the same black column should fully occupy the entire height of the page.
I would be grateful for any constructive responses.
And I posted my code in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqwEZL

Comment: Create your own class and give padding for that

Comment: What padding? For which element?

Answer (score 0):

Bit unsure what you mean, but do you mean this?:

```
<div class="container-fluid main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 left_top">Left</div>

        <div class="col-lg-8 right_top">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 second">2</div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 third">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8 bottom_center">Our tabs</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No! It's not a solution!